# persistent logging in log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

How to perform persistent logging in log4j?
Say when i see a log file with WARN log messages by giving command like debug cms stats WARN..
Now when i close this log file,again my default level i.e INFO messages get printed.
I want my previous state messages i.e WARN messages to get printed..
How to perform??

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the CMS (?) that you are using, not with log4j.  Can you provide some more context?

Comment: I want to know if there is some way of achieving this persistence of keeping the previous level by modifying configuration file.We are using properties file.

Comment: let me take an example.. say now my level is set to warn,so all warn messages will be logged.Now when i close my session after seeing all those warn messages,i wish to see logs of same level i.e warn again.But according to my curent configuration when i start a new session my level is set to default again i.e INFO,which i don't want,i want warn level logs,which i was seeing when i closed my session. please help me with this problem..

Answer (score 0):

Persistence of interactive changes made to logger settings would be something that the application would need to take care of.

As far as log4j is concerned, it simply reads a configuration from a properties file or XML file, and initializes.  Adjustments made after that by application code are not persisted, and (AFAIK) there is no provision in log4j for doing that.   (Yes I'm sure of that.)

The best I can come up with is [this page](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-change-my-log4j-settings-while-my-web-application-is-running.html) that talks about reloading the log4j configs while an application is running.  AFAIK, that's not what you want.

Comment: Are you sure log4j doesn't support persistent logging? Can you suggest some way to do the same..please help as i am stuck at this point.